# How to pad strings with zeros in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, padding

I have a situation where I have an array that has values that are alpha-numeric.

I am looking to loop through them and print out the values with padded 0s.

When I have an array and loop through them normally, it works fine:

```
acct = ["123425326AA", "234123412341234AA", "12342342CP", "12342314234", "5"]

acct.each { |acct| puts acct }

Output:
$ruby main.rb
123425326AA
234123412341234AA
12342342CP
12342314234
5
```

However, when I try to play with padded 0s is where I run into problems.
I have tried playing around with  `%#d` but I am not understanding it.  For example I am trying to pad it with 23 "0"s  using `%23d`  in the loop.

The type of output I am looking for is the following:

```
000000000000123425326AA
000000234123412341234AA
000000000000012342342CP
00000000000012342314234
00000000000000000000005
```

I tried playing around with this code and it mentioned something about integers and my array values does contain some alphas and I am not sure if this is the root cause.  But here are some examples of code that I was trying to play around with.

```
acct.each { |i| puts "%23d" % i }

Output:
$ruby main.rb
main.rb:17:in `%': invalid value for Integer(): "123425326AA" (ArgumentError)
    from main.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
    from main.rb:17:in `each'
    from main.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

From here, I tried to change my array order to the following and it partially worked and was able to process the values that were numbers only but failed once it reached an alpha-numeric value. In addition, it also did not place 0s but replaced it with X amount of spaces.

```
acct = ["5", "12342314234", "234123412341234AA", "12342342CP", "123425326AA"]
acct.each { |acct| puts "%23d" % acct }

Output:
$ruby main.rb
                      5
            12342314234
main.rb:18:in `%': invalid value for Integer(): "234123412341234AA" (ArgumentError)
    from main.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    from main.rb:18:in `each'
    from main.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

I think some type of formatting is needed but I am not sure how to implement that. I did see in some posts where they would add `int.to_s` but was not sure:

```
acct.each { |acct| puts "%23d" % acct.to_s }
```

Comment: Rather than write code, I'd recommend playing with this in IRB.

Comment: You cannot use the method [String#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-25) or its close-cousin [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) to do what you want to do. They both use the format directives listed in `sprintf`'s doc. There is a flag `0` to be placed immediately after the percentage sign to pad left with zeroes, but that is only applicable to numeric fields (e.g., `"%010d" % 123 #=> "0000000123"`), whereas you have a string field (`s`).

Comment: ...You could write `("%23s" % "12342342CP").tr(' ','0') #=> "000000000000012342342CP"`, but the method `String#rjust`, as @Amadan suggests, is purpose-built for this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* a zero-padding function for Strings in Ruby:

```
puts acct.rjust(23, '0')
```

Comment: This worked out well! I edited the code as follows and got the desired output:
`acct.each { |acct| puts acct.rjust(23, '0') }`

Answer (score 2):

There's no zero-padding function for Strings in Ruby but making your own isn't hard:

```
def zero_pad(str, length)
  '0' * (length - str.length) + str
end
```

**Edit**: Amadan has pointed out there *is* such a function!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply @tadman,

I will give it a shot.  

Please forgive my ignorance but for this function and in relation to this use-case would it look something similar to this?
`def zero_pad(acct, length)
  '0' * (23 - str.length) + acct
end`
and I would make a call to "zero_pad"?

Comment: In this case it's just a stand-alone method, so `zero_pad('test', 6)` for example gives you `"00test"`.